# How to add new row in csv using Python panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello this is my `csv` data

```
        Age      Name
0       22  George
1       33  lucas
2       22  Nick
3       12  Leo
4       32 Adriano
5       53  Bram
6       11  David
7       32  Andrei
8       22 Sergio
```

i want to use `if else statement` , for example if George is  adult create new row and insert `+`
i mean

```
Age      Name       Adul
22       George    +
```

What is best way?

This is my code Which i am using to read data from csv

```
import pandas as pd
produtos = pd.read_csv('User.csv', nrows=9)
print(produtos)
for i, produto in produtos.iterrows():
    print(i,produto['Age'],produto['Name'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to create a new *column* (not row) call "Adul". You can do this with `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np

produtos["Adul"] = np.where(produtos["Age"].ge(18), "+", np.nan)
```

###### Edit:

To only do this for a specific name, you could use:

```
name = input("Name")

if name in produtos["Name"].tolist():
    if produtos.loc[produtos["Name"]==name, "Age"] >= 18:
        produtos.loc[produtos["Name"]==name, "Adul"] = "+"
```

Comment: If  i want to check name from terminal ? for example 
name = str(input("Name"))
and check if name is in already my csv create new column and insert +

Comment: @IrakliGhvinianidze - See the edit. Are the names in your dataframe unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
produtos["Adul"] = np.where(produtos["Age"] >= 18, "+", np.nan)
```